# c++ dynamically add WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL extended style to ListView and its LVCOLUMN

Tags: c++, listview, winapi, visual-c++, localization

I have a ListView created by `CreateWindowExW()` with `WC_LISTVIEWW`. I then create columns using `LVCOLUMNW` and set the texts via `pszText`.

I would like the column texts of this list view to be aligned to the right, so I added `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL` to the extended style when doing `CreateWindowExW()`. Then when I create and add the columns to this ListView, text/name/title of each column are aligned to the right, as expected, so far so good.

The issue is, if I exclude `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL` from `CreateWindowExW()`, and instead, use `SetWindowLongPtrW` to add this RTL extended style to the ListView, and then, create and add `LVCOLUMNW`s, it would has no effect, the text/name/title of each column are still left-aligned, even the order of columns are not RTL, the first added column would be at far left, whereas with `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL` taking effect, it should start from far right.

`SetWindowLongPtrW` returns a non-zero value which matches the initial extended style combination, so the function call should be a success. The only thing I am thinking now is maybe with ListView and `LVCOLUMNW`, `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL` simply cannot be added after ListView had already been created?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: That is also a good idea for me to validit or narrow down the issue, thanks. I'll see if I can put something together and if I do I'll try uploading it.

Comment: This is the wrong approach. RTL layout is intended for languages that are read right to left (Hebrew, Arabic, etc). If you want column text aligned to the right, use the flag in the LVM_COLUMN struct explicitly defined for that purpose: LVCFMT_RIGHT

Comment: Thank you @Luke this may just be exactly what I was looking for, setting the fmt member of LVM_COLUMN struct to be LVCFMT_RIGHT. I will try it out and report back later tomorrow.

Comment: There is no document about how does `WC_LISTVIEW` implement the reading direction. My guess is `SetWindowLongPtr` `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL` on the top window of `WC_LISTVIEW` skips the working code and takes no effect. Luke's solution should work on list items.

Comment: Sorry for following up late. @Luke 's answer really was the right approach to go. Thank you YangXiaopo, although I'm not 100% sure what you meant by skipping the working code, but you pointing out the lack of document regarding reading direction, and directing me to Luke's solution, were very helpful. Luke if you could write your suggestion into an answer, I shall gladly accept it to be the correct one. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `LVCFMT_RIGHT` format flag on the [`LVCOLUMN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-lvcolumnw) structure.

Comment: Thank you Luke, sorry for the delayed response. I had accept this as the correct answer.